# Old Crystal Report painfully slow in CR 2008 viewer

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have a VB6 app which connects to either a SQL Server or Oracle Database.  It includes some Crystal Reports, made with an old version (CR 8.5).

I'm working on upgrading the Crystal viewer to CR 2008 (using Interop Forms Toolkit).
Everything is working fairly well, but I am seeing a few reports which are painfully slow to appear.  Other reports are perfectly fine.

I would appreciate any tips for things to look at that would cause a crystal report to appear quickly in the CR 8.5 preview window, but slowly in the CR 2008 preview window.

Comment: Further testing has shown that the type of database (SQL Server vs. Oracle) is actually not a factor.  Question edited to remove the suggestion that the problem only happened when the db was Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that vastly sped up the processing (previewing or printing of the reports):

- Open the report in the Crystal 2008 editor
- Database menu, select "Verify Database"
- Save

Doing that changed some fields from "PersistentMemoField" to "StringField", and removed some "DatabaseName" values.  Anyway, I'm happy with the results.

Answer (score 2):

The most recent Crystal reports version supported by VB6 is Crystal XI. I know that you can create a COM object in .NET and call it from VB6 , but this will not change the fact that Crystal 2008 is not supported. Sooner or later you will hit a report where the VB6 app will have issues, which you cannot resolve . To check if this is the case for the current reports create a temp .NET project and run one of them. If the report works fine obviously the issue is VB6. Of course there might be other reasons for the slow reports. Did you change the machine where you are running them ? If yes , do you have the same printers installed and the same drives (including  mapped drives) on the new machine?

P.S. Actually to test the report in .NET you don't need to create a project. It will be easier if you download one the existing .NET Crystal viewers on the market. Usually they have trial mode , which will be enough for your test. Let me know if this will work better for you , I can post some links

Comment: **Thanks** for the answer.  A particular report previewed from my VB6 app with the old Crystal runtime will appear practically instantaneously.  The same report previewed from my VB6 app with the 2008 Crystal runtime will see a delay of about 15 seconds.  When previewing the same report from a .NET app that I wrote, the delay is only reduced to about 12 seconds.  So I think there is something in the report that the new runtime doesn't like, and I don't think that "VB6 with the 2008 runtime" is the problem.

Comment: If the delay is just 15 seconds most likely this is related to .NET. Try to run the report twice and check what is the second time. During the first start your .NET application will load all components , which will take some time. VB6 is using the old ActiveX components , which are smaller and loaded much faster

Comment: Yeah, the 2nd time it is quicker.  But the quickest is still unacceptably slow.

Comment: Do you have subreports ?

Comment: Yes, there are subreports.

Comment: In Crystal 8.5 there is an option to reimport subreport. Can you check if this option is false ? Check in Cr 8.5

Comment: Options, New_Report tab, "Re-import Subreports When Opening Reports" is not checked.

Comment: If this option is not checked then the difference is coming from the .NET components. BTW did you check all subreports for this option ? My guess is that they are OK, because the delay is too small. If the option is ON and the subreport is not available then the delay is usually at least 30 seconds per subreport. However it worth to check each of the subreports just to make sure they are not reimported.